# osmnx returning .... unexpected... bearings

Tags: osmnx

I'm trying to find all streets in a given city that run along a specific bearing, I'm building up a list of those edges like this:

```
G = ox.graph_from_place('Milpitas, CA')
G = ox.add_edge_bearings(ox.get_undirected(G))
sixtydegrees = []
uninteresting = []
for u, v, k, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True):
    if np.isnan(data['bearing']):
        uninteresting.append((u, v, k))
    else:
         b = round(data['bearing'])
         if (b == 60 or b == 240):
             sixtydegrees.append((u, v, k))
         else:
             uninteresting.append((u, v, k))
G.remove_edges_from(G.edges - uninteresting)
```

However that produces edges like the one below that include multiple segments along multiple bearings. While the beginning and end nodes are 60º from each other, the edge is made up of 4 segments none of which run along 60º.  It's imaginary line running through the park, connecting origin and destination nodes that runs along 60º.

[image]

osmnx.bearing.add_edge_bearings is (by design) a simple calculation of the angle between origin node to destination node.

To *really* find streets, which probably means sections of streets as described above given how OSM data is organized, that are along a given bearing, am I going to have to iterate through the xy pairs and calculate each bearing?  Or is there another more elegant solution I'm missing?

Comment: If you set `simplify=False` when you create the graph, you'll get straightline street segments. See the docs.

Comment: Thanks, that helps clarify a lot.  So with simplify=True, edges are highways between intersections (or a dead end) and with simplify=False, edges are each straight line that makes up a highway.  

Working with that larger set of edges is cleaner and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got working, wondering if there is a better way.

```
for u, v, k, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True):
    # iterate over edges
    if v==u:
        # loops don't have meaningful bearings
        uninteresting.append((u, v, k))
    else:
        lons, lats = data['geometry'].xy
        lat1 = None
        lon1 = None
        hit = False
        for lon, lat in zip(lons, lats):
            if lat1:
                b = round(ox.bearing.get_bearing((lat1, lon1),  (lat, lon)))
                d = round(ox.distance.great_circle_vec(lat1, lon1, lat, lon))
                if d > 250: #ignore segments shorter than 250m
                    hit = hit or (59 <= b <= 61)
            lat1 = lat
            lon1 = lon
        if hit:
            sixtydegrees.append((u, v, k))
        else:
            uninteresting.append((u, v, k))
```